# ColdFusion Multi Check isDefined(session) and is not blank

Tags: coldfusion

I am trying to say if this isDefined and is not blank show this..

```
<cfif (isDefined("session.checkout.info.Certificate_2")) is not "">
```

I also tried:

```
<cfif (isDefined("session.checkout.info.Certificate_2")) neq "">
```

Will someone please tell me why this still shows when the string is empty?

Comment: Tip: The phrase "does not work" ... does not tell us much ;-). With any question, it is best to summarize 1) the actual results and 2) how they differ from what you expected.  Including all the pertinent info up front ensures you get the best response. Also, I would recommend reading over the docs first. [`IsDefined`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7fbd.html) returns "true" or "false".  Neither of those is an empty string, so as you would expect, the cfif expression will always evaluate to true.

Comment: How about `<cfif (isDefined("session.checkout.info.Certificate_2"))>`

Comment: That only verifies the variable exists. It does not test the value. Depending on whether they set a default it may or may not work. (Side note, no extra parenthesis needed here.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider using structKeyExists (it has lower overhead than isDefined) but here you go:

```
<cfif
    isDefined("session.checkout.info.Certificate_2")
    AND session.checkout.info.Certificate_2 NEQ "">
```

If it exists it will then check to see if it's empty. If it doesn't exist, it won't check the value.

Comment: case is not sensitive in CFML.