# Error - Element X is Undefined in Session

Tags: session, coldfusion, cfml

Getting this Error

> ELEMENT CURRLANGUAGE IS UNDEFINED IN SESSION.

Don't understand why. It was working fine until yesterday

```
<cfif session.currLanguage eq 'English'>
   <cfset session.currLanguage = ''>
</cfif>
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that sessions work at on your web server? Can you create just a sample application.cfm + page.cfm and see if they work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ColdFusion Multi Check isDefined(session) and is not blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28225340/coldfusion-multi-check-isdefinedsession-and-is-not-blank)

Answer (score 9):

Because `currLanguage` is not defined in the session scope. Womp Womp.

Try this to see what IS defined.

```
<cfdump var="#SESSION#">
```

It could be that something is not being set when it should. We'd have to see your code to tell for sure. If you think it's working okay and want to prevent unnecessary error messages in the future, you can do a check like this:

```
<cfif structKeyExists(SESSION, "currLanguage") AND SESSION.currLanguage is "English">
Logic Logic Logic
</cfif>
```

Comment: Not much Help there. the page rund in coldfusion server. Has lots of session which is called form 2-3 different pages. I tried the cfdup var session code and also tried your code above....not working...it goes to another session and gives me same error

Comment: Did `application.cfc` change recently?

Comment: I have Application.cfm. No not changed recently

Answer (score 1):

Please confirm those too

1. Please check the value update in the session scope properly.
2. The session scope will be created based on application name. so if we created the application name as dynamic or updated recently then the session scope will be created as new